# How to change a specific third level character? [Ubuntu 14.10]

Tags: shortcut-keys, compose-key

For example, pressing *third level chooser* (not *compose key*, as I posted earlier) + *v* = *@*. However, I want *third level chooser* + *v* to print *#*. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This technique is known as "composing a key".  I write Spanish but on US-keyboard layout,and I use `ALT`+ any number to make accents, but this also hold many others characters as well.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey should help you on that - but scroll little further down until you see 'third level'.

Comment: Your link shows how to change compose key combinations. I've tried this (copying and modifying .XCompose, and adding "export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"" to .Xsession). The changes had no effect. However, I didn't want to change the compose key combinations, but rather a specific third level key. (I thought that the compose key and third level chooser are the same thing.) I've modified my original question accordingly.

Comment: I managed to adjust the compose key combination (copied utf8 compose table to ~/.XCompose and modified it to suit my needs, and added "xport GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"" to the beginning of ~/.profile). Do you have any idea if I can do the same for the third level modifiers?